# How can I query each field?

Tags: elasticsearch

- Sample document

```
{
    "_id": "1",
    "DOC": [
        {
            "key": "A B C"
        },
        {
            "key": "B C D"
        },
        {
            "key": "C D E"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to highlight document's each `key` having `A and C`.

But all queries I've tried search whole documents.

If I search `A and C`, they give me

```
"highlight": {
    "DOC.key": [
        "<keyword>A</keyword> B <keyword>C</keyword>",
        "B <keyword>C</keyword> D",
        "<keyword>C</keyword> D E"
    ]
}
```

`"<keyword>A</keyword> B <keyword>C</keyword>"` is correct.

But I didn't want `"B <keyword>C</keyword> D"` and `"<keyword>C</keyword> D E"`.

I want to highlight `key` which have `A` with `C`

```
"highlight": {
    "DOC.key": [
        "<keyword>A</keyword> B <keyword>C</keyword>"
    ]
}
```

How can I search it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal arrays are flattened in elastic search. So after indexing document has no idea that all "keys" are separate.

If you want to treat each "key"  as separate entity, you need to declare it as [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)

**Mapping**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "DOC":{
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "DOC",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "DOC.key": {
            "query": "A C",
            "operator": "and"
          }
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {
        "highlight": {
          "fields": {
            "DOC.key": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
{
        "_index" : "index61",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "QUI7Dn0BLZ9gNW_AS1dp",
        "_score" : 1.1037275,
        "_source" : {
          "DOC" : [
            {
              "key" : "A B C"
            },
            {
              "key" : "B C D"
            },
            {
              "key" : "C D E"
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "DOC" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.1037275,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "index61",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "QUI7Dn0BLZ9gNW_AS1dp",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "DOC",
                    "offset" : 0
                  },
                  "_score" : 1.1037275,
                  "_source" : {
                    "key" : "A B C"
                  },
                  "highlight" : {
                    "DOC.key" : [
                      "<em>A</em> B <em>C</em>"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
```